# SQL order groups in table without GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, select

I have a *quote_logs* table where there are groups of logs(about 8 logs in each group). Every group has *quote_log_group* field which has the same value for the group(for example 1530599717507).

I need SQL statement to get **all** quote logs, **sorted by** the *net_charge* field in each group.
Rows in the table look like this:

[image]

Expected sample output:

```
*id*  *net_charge* *quote_log_group*
5 - 110 - group1
7 - 120 - group1
2 - 130 - group1
4 - 140 - group1
3 - 150 - group1

11 - 110 - group2
15 - 120 - group2
12 - 130 - group2
13 - 140 - group2
14 - 150 - group2
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output? also, post what you have tried.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: You can **ORDER BY** multiple columns. For instance first on _quote_log_group_ followed by _net_charge_ : **ORDER BY quote_log_group, net_charge** See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order the query by `quote_log_group` to get all the rows in the same group one of the other and then by `net_charge`:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     quote_logs
ORDER BY quote_log_group, net_charge
```